# Regex for Username?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, regex

I am using C# and jQuery to valid a username with Regex. Just learning :) So far I have

```
UserName = "[a-zA-Z0-9]";
```

But this doesn't stop symbols ? How to ensure that no symbols or " . " or " _ " ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That regex says "At least one letter or number" you want "Every character from the start to the end is a letter or number"

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
```

Comment: oh great thanks :) wow fast reply! ill try this. thanks so much

Comment: As an addition, typically usernames are not allowed to start with digits - to ensure this, use `"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"`.

Comment: And if you want min/max length restrictions: `"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{3,9}$"` (min 4 and max 10)

Comment: so this works ? ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,11}$ - for no symbols, min/max 3-11 ?

Comment: @Gabriel: check that again; Murray removed the separate letter in the front.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add @ , . %^&* digits character in below regex
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9._@#$% ]+$"