# C# Regex for a username with a few restrictions

Tags: c#, regex

Similar to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763995/regex-for-username).

I am trying to validate a username with the following restrictions:

- Must start with a letter or number
- Must be 3 to 15 characters in length
- Symbols include: **. - _ ( ) [ ]**
- Symbols cannot be adjacent, but letters and numbers can

Edit:

- Letters and numbers are a-z A-Z 0-9

Been stumped for a while. I'm new to regex.

Comment: When you say "symbols cannot appear consecutively," do you mean `.-_()[]`, or do you mean `A-Za-z0-9` are not allowed to repeat, as well?

Comment: What will people do without their double-hockey-sticks? (`][`)

Comment: When you say "letter" or "number" do you mean a-z and 0-9, or should foreign letters and numbers be allowed too? For example, a Chinese person would regard this as a valid number: 九

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not so clean to express a set of unrelated rules in a single regular expression, but it can be done by using lookaround assertions [(Rubular)](http://rubular.com/r/kWrdNwWmqg):

```
@"^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])(?!.*[._()\[\]-]{2})[A-Za-z0-9._()\[\]-]{3,15}$"
```

Explanation:

```
(?=[A-Za-z0-9])            Must start with a letter or number
(?!.*[._()\[\]-]{2})       Cannot contain two consecutive symbols
[A-Za-z0-9._()\[\]-]{3,15} Must consist of between 3 to 15 allowed characters
```

You might want to consider if this would be easier to read and more maintable as a list of simpler regular expressions, all of which must validate successfully, or else write it in ordinary C# code.

Comment: Using a regex for a length check is inefficient, unclear, and subject to breakage.  (I think Mark's code is broken, as it looks like it requires a letter or number followed by 3-15 MORE characters, so it actually matches 4-16 characters.)  Using a separate test for each requirement will be far easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply. This did work too, but the period is missing from the (?!.*[_()\[\]-\{2}) part.

should be (?!.*[._()\[\]-]{2}) otherwise a period can follow any symbol

Comment: @Ben: unclear, yes, but Mark's code uses zero-width assertion (it consumes no characters), so the length constraint is preserved.

Comment: @Marlon: You are correct, that was a copy/paste error. I've updated my post.

Comment: I think this is a clear and succinct way to describe the rules.  The only ugliness is that all the rules are mashed together in one string, rather than being split up into 3 variables.  To mitigate this, you could use string concatenation and split up the different rules into multiple lines: `"^" <newline> + "(?=[A-Z...])" <newline> + "(?!...)" <newline> + "[A-Z...]{3,15}" <newline> + "$"`

Answer (score 16):

As an optimization to Mark's answer:

```
^(?=.{3,15}$)([A-Za-z0-9][._()\[\]-]?)*$
```

Explanation:

```
(?=.{3,15}$)                   Must be 3-15 characters in the string
([A-Za-z0-9][._()\[\]-]?)*   The string is a sequence of alphanumerics,
                               each of which may be followed by a symbol
```

This one permits Unicode alphanumerics:

```
^(?=.{3,15}$)((\p{L}|\p{N})[._()\[\]-]?)*$
```

This one is the Unicode variant, plus uses non-capturing groups:

```
^(?=.{3,15}$)(?:(?:\p{L}|\p{N})[._()\[\]-]?)*$
```

Comment: +1 That's quite a useful variation because it avoids repeating the definitions of "letter or number" and "symbol". You don't need the innermost parentheses.

Comment: You're right, that was a parenthesized atom.  Redundant parens removed.

Comment: It should also be faster, since there's only one lookahead, and it's much simpler.